# Merge multiple array to an single array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I need your help,
I am devloping a javascript client that consumes data from distant server,
data from server are coming in this form:

```
[
["Thabit", "Doghri", 2, 1],
["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 2],
["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 3],
["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 4],
["Thabit", "Doghri", 2, 5],
["Thabit", "Doghri", 3, 6],
["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 7],
["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 8],
["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 9],
["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 10],
["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 11],
["Thabit", "Doghri", 5, 12],
["Ramzi", "Mejri", 2, 1],
["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 2],
["Ramzi", "Mejri", 2, 3],
["Ramzi", "Mejri", 2, 4],
["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 5],
["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 6],
["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 7],
["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 8],
["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 9],
["Ramzi", "Mejri", 4, 10],
["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 11],
["Ramzi", "Mejri", 3, 12]
]
```

what i need now is to get an array like this :

```
  [{
      name: 'Thabet Doghri',
      data: [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5]
  }, {
      name: 'Ramzi Mejri',
      data: [4, 6, 1, 3, 7, 9, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 5, 9]
  }]
```

How to proceed plese ? I am confused

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Where are you getting data for Ramzi Mejri? If that is just random typing then your example needs to reflect the actual desired response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a reduce and map approach

```js
var tmp=  data.reduce((a, c) => {
    const name = c.slice(0,2).join(' ');
    a[name] = a[name] || {name: name, data:[]};
    a[name].data.push(c[2])
    return a
  }, {})
var res = Object.keys(tmp).map(key=>tmp[key]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [
    ["Thabit", "Doghri", 2, 1],
    ["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 2],
    ["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 3],
    ["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 4],
    ["Thabit", "Doghri", 2, 5],
    ["Thabit", "Doghri", 3, 6],
    ["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 7],
    ["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 8],
    ["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 9],
    ["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 10],
    ["Thabit", "Doghri", 1, 11],
    ["Thabit", "Doghri", 5, 12],
    ["Ramzi", "Mejri", 2, 1],
    ["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 2],
    ["Ramzi", "Mejri", 2, 3],
    ["Ramzi", "Mejri", 2, 4],
    ["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 5],
    ["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 6],
    ["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 7],
    ["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 8],
    ["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 9],
    ["Ramzi", "Mejri", 4, 10],
    ["Ramzi", "Mejri", 1, 11],
    ["Ramzi", "Mejri", 3, 12]
  ]
</script>
```